# Does Salesforce REST API (not the Apex Rest API) inherently respect field level permissions

Tags: rest-api, permissions

Does Salesforce REST API (not the Apex Rest API) inherently respect field level permissions while fetching data ? 
Tried to find this in the SF documentation but no luck. Any help is highly appriciated

Answer (score 3):

Invoking a custom Apex REST Web service method always uses system context. Consequently, the current user's credentials are not used, and any user who has access to these methods can use their full power, regardless of permissions, field-level security, or sharing rules. Developers who expose methods using the Apex REST annotations should therefore take care that they are not inadvertently exposing any sensitive data.

> Apex class methods that are exposed through the Apex REST API don't
>   enforce object permissions and field-level security by default. We
>   recommend that you make use of the appropriate object or field
>   describe result methods to check the current user’s access level on
>   the objects and fields that the Apex REST API method is accessing. See
>   DescribeSObjectResult Class and DescribeFieldResult Class.
>
> Also, sharing rules (record-level access) are enforced only when
>   declaring a class with the with sharing keyword. This requirement
>   applies to all Apex classes, including to classes that are exposed
>   through Apex REST API. To enforce sharing rules for Apex REST API
>   methods, declare the class that contains these methods with the with
>   sharing keyword. See Using the with sharing or without sharing
>   Keywords.

Reference from [developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_exposing_data.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @RCS. This applies for REST API's implemented in Apex, but I want to know what is the case with Salesforce REST API (not the Apex Rest API).

Comment: @GopalRao - Same rules apply

Comment: You can go with ESAPI to implement FLS and sharing in your webservice.
 https://github.com/forcedotcom/force-dot-com-esapi

Comment: I tried this out, the same does not apply to Salesforce rest API's

Comment: That is because they implemented what is outlined in the doc. It is doing exactly what the doc says. "We recommend that you make use of the appropriate object or field describe result methods to check the current user’s access level on the objects and fields that the Apex REST API method is accessing."

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in my dev org, 
the Salesforce default rest api honors both sharing and field level permissions of the user(whose sessionId/access_token we are using) while fetching data.

Comment: That is because they implemented what is outlined in the doc. It is doing exactly what the doc says. "We recommend that you make use of the appropriate object or field describe result methods to check the current user’s access level on the objects and fields that the Apex REST API method is accessing."

Comment: Yeah exactly. Its recommend but not compulsory in in case of Apex Rest api's, where as in Saleforce rest api's, we don't have that option the feild level permissions are by default honoured

Comment: Your putting the cart before the horse. SF Rest API's are just like the ones you write. They implemented FLS. If you write an API you should implement FLS. They operate the same.

Comment: I understood your point.  But what I wanted to imply is, we still have an option of not enforcing FLS in case of apex apis if we wish so, as they are in our control(though this is not a recommended practice). But same is not tpossible with SF apis

Comment: True, when looking at it from the user of the API though its all the same. If you in your REST api do not enforce it the user of the API has no control. Its all how the API is designed